# How to fit an image to ImageButton programmatically

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to set background of ImageButton using this image: [image]

and code:

OnCreate:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LightImageButton lightImageButton = new LightImageButton(false, getApplicationContext());
    ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    imageButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(lightImageButton.getCurrentImage()));
    imageButton.setOnClickListener(lightImageButton);

}
```

Auxiliary class:

```
public class LightImageButton implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final int bulbOnImg = R.drawable.bulb_on;
private static final int bulbOffImg = R.drawable.bulb_off;
private boolean state;
private Context context;
private int currentImage;

public LightImageButton(boolean state, Context context) {
    this.state = state;
    this.context = context;
    currentImage = bulbOffImg;
}

public int getCurrentImage() {
    return currentImage;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) v;

    if (state) {
        currentImage = bulbOnImg;
    } else {
        currentImage = bulbOffImg;
    }
    state = !state;
    btn.setBackground(context.getResources().getDrawable(currentImage));
}
}
```

But next result is received:
[image]

I want to have correctly scaled image. How can I do it? Maybe there are any better way to do this using some other clickable class instead of ImageButton?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this:

```
imageButton.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(lightImageButton.getCurrentImage()));
```

With:

```
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.your_bulb);
imageButton.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! For me ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE suited best.